# ASMX dll not loaded when in subfolder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asmx

I am using ASP.NET (3.5) webforms. I have a plugin for a website that contains an .ascx file and an .asmx file. My folder structure looks like this:

- MainWebSiteFolder

  - bin
  - Plugins

    - Plugin1

      - Plugin1.ascx
      - Plugin1.asmx
      - bin

        - Plugin1.dll

At runtime, the main website (using the  web.config tag) can find the Plugin1.dll and load the Plugin1.ascx into the webpage. The Plugin1.ascx contains javascript code that calls the Plugin1.asmx, but IIS can't find the Plugin1.asmx codebehind because it's looking for Plugin1.dll in the main website's bin folder instead of the plugin's bin folder.

Trying to reach the asmx directly via URL (http://MyWebSite/Plugins/Plugin1/Plugin1.asmx) results in the following error:

```
RunTime Error

Could not create type 'MyNamespace.Plugin1'.

Line 1:  <%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="Plugin1.asmx.cs" Class="MyNamespace.Plugin1" %>
```

There are several similar questions out there, but none of them solve my problem because **I just own the plugin, so I don't want to copy the plugin.dll into the main website's bin folder** (because, when the main website is upgraded, its bin folder is emptied. I don't have control over this). I also don't want to make the asmx its own separate IIS application because it needs to be able to share a session with the main website.

Is there anything I can do to connect the asmx file with its dll inside the subfolder?

Comment: In addition to answer below [see this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=4d0ef4fb-f8ae-4355-a658-3c0432c98dbe). I haven't tried this so **test it** - re: it seems you need to add `<%@ Assembly Name="Foo1" %>` and `<%@ Import Namespace="FooNamespace" %>`. Hth...

Answer (score 1):

Check if adding a web.config to the Plugins or your Plugin1 directory ([web.config inheritance](https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/10-things-asp-net-developers-should-know-about-web-config-inheritance-and-overrides)), containing an assembly probing-element works (see [probing Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN).

Comment: My Plugin1 directory already has a web.config, so I tried adding   <runtime>  
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">  
    <probing privatePath="Plugins\Plugin1\bin"/>  
      </assemblyBinding>  
   </runtime>. No luck.

Comment: Seems like the runtime-element can't be inherited in web.config, although I'm unable to find documentation on this. If you add the runtime/probing element to the application's web.config your dll will be found, but I guess this isn't an option.